# Image fails to be uploaded on s3 bucket using node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload images on s3bucket using s3FS. Bucket is created successfully,but somehow the api through which i am trying to upload an image, is giving me error saying your path is not defined. However bucket is created in aws,but image is not there.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fs = require('fs');
var S3FS = require('s3fs');
var s3fsImpl = new S3FS('folder', {
    accessKeyId: 'id',
    secretAccessKey: 'key'
});

s3fsImpl.create();

var multiparty = require('connect-multiparty'),
    multipartyMiddleware = multiparty();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
// var multer = require('multer');
// var uuid = require("uuid");
var app = express();
var config = require('./config.js');
var morgan = require('morgan');
// var path = require('path');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var foodtrucklist = require('./controller/foodtrucklist.js');
var login = require('./controller/login.js');
var itemInfo = require('./controller/item_info.js');
var review = require('./controller/reviews.js');
var popularitems = require('./controller/popularitems.js');
var foodtruck = require('./model/datafoodtruck');
var truckData = require('./model/foodtruck.js');
var webToken = require('./controller/webtoken.js');
var userprofile = require('./controller/userprofile.js');
var notificationdata = require('./model/dataNotifications.js');
var notification = require('./controller/notifications.js');
var foodtruckItemList = require('./controller/item_list_foodtruck.js');
var orderList = require('./controller/orders_foodtruck.js');
var ordermanagement = require('./controller/ordermanagement.js');

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/quflip');

mongoose.connection.once('connected', function() {
    console.log("Connected to database")
    foodtruck.save(function(err, foodtrucks) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
    });
    notificationdata.save(function(err, notifs) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
    });
});

app.use(multipartyMiddleware);
app.post('/testupload', function(req, res) {
    var file = req.files.file;
    var stream = fs.creatReadStream(file.path);
    return s3fsImpl.writeFile(file.originalFilename, stream).then(function() {
        fs.unlink(file.path, function(err) {
            if (err) console.error(err);
        })
        res.json({
            status:'200',
            message:'uploaded'
        })
    })
});
```

errors

```
TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;path&#39; of undefined
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\app.js:64:41
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at multipart (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\connect-multiparty\index.js:50:53)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at expressInit (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:33:5)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at query (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\query.js:44:5)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: `var file = req.files.file;` Here `file` seems undefined.

Comment: I know that, but I have already passed data from postman.

Comment: Then it will help to see your request.

Comment: request url :http://localhost:3000/testUpload ,  "form-data"         ,    body parameters --->     file: filename.jpg

Comment: Can you provide request as curl command? Are you sure you're sending file content in request and trying to read it from right place in the request?

Comment: curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: ec169a3d-7163-29a6-a66a-d9d1e2c99e2b" -F "file=@bookmark-g-mdpi.png" "http://localhost:3000/testUpload"